# FInding Swing panels with org.fest.swing.fixture.FrameFixture::panel(), it requires panel to be showing?

Tags: swing, unit-testing, fest

I want to use FEST to test that a Swing component is invisible.

I try to use `org.fest.swing.fixture.FrameFixture`method `panel(“foo”)` but that fails since it requires `requireShowing=true.`

What is idiomatic approach using FEST to find a panel irregardless if it's visible right now?

```
Assert.assertFalse(panel.getFooPanel().isVisible()); // works ok
myFrameFixture.panel(“foo”).requireNotVisible(); // fails
```

The second line gives this...

```
     javax.swing.JPanel[name='foo']

org.fest.swing.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to find component
using matcher 
org.fest.swing.core.NameMatcher[name='foo, type=javax.swing.JPanel, requireShowing=true].
```

**EDIT :**

I tied a similar test with a JComboBox, using the pattern suggested by 
Jay Fichadia, but it still seems to require the item to be visible before I invoke `.requireNotVisible()`
e.g. trying `new JComboBoxFixture(frame.robot,"grid_combo");` alone  (without the actual requireNotVisible() check) gives ...

```
    Caused an ERROR
Unable to find component using matcher org.fest.swing.core.NameMatcher[name='grid_combo', type=javax.swing.JComboBox, requireShowing=true].
```

despite the fact we have in the Component hierarchy:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox[name='grid_combo', selectedItem='A', contents=['A', 'B'], editable=false, enabled=false, visible=false, showing=false]
```

Comment: Did you add your panel to the frame? And called setVisible(false)?

Comment: @keuleJ yes to both. Updated question with more info.

Comment: And you do panel.setName("foo")? Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: It might have something to do with 'showing'. Your matcher says: requireShowing=true and the component showing=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered same problem and after seeing no answer here, I found a solution myself.

The problem is that frameFixture by default look only for components that are visible. So if you want to search for not visible components, you have to change this setting. You can do this by using:

```
myFrameFixture.robot.settings().componentLookupScope(ComponentLookupScope.ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `new JPanelFixture(robot,"foo").requireNotVisible()`;

Comment: No luck with that approach @jay-fichadia. Edited question to say that.

Comment: How do you acquire FrameFixture object?
Also, are your UI components enabled? I mean in your UI code are you disabling them or something ?